# Javascript detect allow only one click and keyup on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code in order to show a message when a specific input has been clicked or selected with the tab button. Now  I want to show the message only when the input is clicked for the first time or when the input is selected for the first time. How can I implement the one click only and one keyup only?

```js
 $("#field").on( 'keyup', function( e ) {
        if( e.which == 9 ) {
            alert("test keyup")
        }
    } );

    $("#field").click(function() {
        alert("test click");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="field" name="field_name" type="text" />
```

Comment: Add a bool that will act as a flag

Comment: `one()` instead of `on()` and use the `focus` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `off()` once the message display as below.

Also you can use `one()` instead of `on`

```js
$("#field").on( 'keyup', function( e ) {
        if( e.which == 9 ) {
            alert("test keyup")
            $( this ).off( e );
        }
        
    } );

    $("#field").click(function(e) {
        alert("test click");
        
        $( this ).off( e );
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="field" name="field_name" type="text" />
```

Comment: Thanks @Devsi Odedra , it's exactly what I was looking for! :))))

Comment: Good to here it helps you :)))